# Who derived the fundamental solution for the heat equation

Tags: math-history

Green's function was used in the fundamental solution for heat equation, but did Green actually derive it? I'm asking because both my PDE professor and I are interested in knowing...Thanks!

Comment: This isn't online? I'd think it would be. Sadly, I also do not know.

Comment: Sadly, it's not :(

Comment: Not as far as I know...

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just surprised to hear that.

Comment: Well, the original solution of the heat equation is due to Fourier (guess what method of solution he used). I don't know much about the history though, and I don't know that he solved an inhomogeneous version... he predates Green by a few decades.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks! Do you have a source on this? I saw that wikipedia also implied that it's Fourier.